# Node.js/Socket.io working in everything except Firefox, could this be a cache issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, websocket, socket.io

I was tinkering around with node.js and socket.io and was using Firefox. It was working fine to begin with, but then as I did updates it just stopped working entirely. I tested it by doing the most basic emit/broadcast call (which had been working fine before) and it still didn't work.

It works in every browser I've tested (Chrome, Opera, Safari) except Firefox, my best guess is that this would be some sort of cache issue so I did `npm cache clean` but still no luck. I tried reinstalling node.js and socket.io but it's still not working. I know it's connecting to the server because it's initiating handshakes and says "Welcome to socket.io." if I go directly to the server, but beyond that nothing is working.

If anyone has a clue what might be going on I'd appreciate the help, I'm completely lost.

Comment: All I can say is that given your description, the problem *has* to be with Firefox and not anything else, since everything else is working fine when Firefox is out of the picture.

Comment: Thank you, this comment helped me figure out what was wrong by focusing directly on Firefox rather than my node.js/socket.io setup.

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, I figured out what was causing it was MAMP PRO server names. Instead of using localhost:8888/mysite I had my local host set up to just use mysite.com (much easier for development purposes as I'm sure you all know) and for some reason this is causing an issue with Firefox and socket.io.

So if anyone is experiencing a similar problem and are using MAMP with a dedicating server name, try using the direct local host path instead and see if it works.